# Vuetify Multiple fixed toolbars and nav drawers

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a requirement to have a toolbar fixed at the top of the page and then another toolbar that is always visible below that (inside the v-content) but im having trouble figuring out how to make it sticky within the v-content and also respond with width adjustments from the drawers.

Using fixed had semi-promising results but it overlaps the main menu, offsetting by the height of the app bar would work but the height is not consistant but i can use $vuetify.application.top but the nav drawer  goes under the menu instead of pushing it.

Id have thought it would be simple if instead of the whole html page scrolling i could have a full height div in my content area that would scroll instead that way i could have the tool bare outside the scrolling area.

Has anyone got any advice ?

See:
https://codepen.io/TrendyTim/pen/jOOWJwV

The v-content's content would typically come from a component via a , i simplified it though to make it more easy to follow by removing vue-router and the sub component nature.

StackOverflow required code for codepen link

````
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
         <v-app-bar
          app
          clipped-right
          color="blue-grey"
          dark
        >

          <v-toolbar-title>App Level Bar - Always at top  -  TOP = {{this.$vuetify.application.top}} BAR= {{this.$vuetify.application.bar}}</v-toolbar-title>
          <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
              <v-btn color="#78909d" @click.stop="showPlanner = !showPlanner">
            <v-icon >mdi-sitemap</v-icon>&nbsp;TOGGLE NAV DRAWER
          </v-btn>
        </v-app-bar>


      <v-navigation-drawer
        mobile-break-point="100"
          v-model="showPlanner"
          app
          clipped
          right
          width="50%"
        >
          <v-list dense>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-exit-to-app</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>This is under the context bar 1</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-exit-to-app</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>This is under the context bar 2</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-exit-to-app</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>This is under the context bar 3</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-exit-to-app</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>This is under the context bar  4</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-content>
                <v-app-bar   fixed :style="{top:toolbarHeight + 'px'}">
          <v-toolbar-title>Context specific app bar </v-toolbar-title>

        </v-app-bar>
                  <div :style="{'padding-top':toolbarHeight + 10  + 'px'}"></div>
    LINE 1<BR>
    LINE 2<BR>
    LINE 3<BR>
    LINE 4<BR>

              <div>
                The 2nd tool bar should always be visible but below the main toolbar but the navigation drawer doesnt push the app bar with the rest of the content.
                <br><br>
                Making the 2nd app bar fixed places it over the top of the main app toolbar so needs a offset, all the content in v-content is from a router-view<br><br>

                Using this.$vuetify.application.top worksish (though not sure if itll have other issues), this.$vuetify.application.bar always returns 0 <br><br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
           This is a long list of content <br>
                This is a long list of content <br>
                  </div>

        </v-content>


        <v-footer
          app
          color="blue-grey"
          class="white--text"
        >
          <span>Vuetify</span>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <span>&copy; 2019</span>
        </v-footer>
      </v-app>
    </div>```
````

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
  showPlanner: true
  }),
computed: {
    toolbarHeight: function () {
      console.log(this.$vuetify.application)
      return this.$vuetify.application.top
    }
  }

})
```